# XlsxReaderWriter Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, excel, xls

I am using XlsxReaderWrite Library

https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter

To create Excel sheet in app

Excel file have 6 sheets in there

while runing "save" function app is getting crashed with message

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Comment: yes its about iOS, sorry for not writing it in question. i am editing it